# Elasticsearch search locked with ransomeware

Tags: elasticsearch

I have not protected elasticsearch, so someone hacked it, left new index with contents where to transfer bitcoins. Data I can regenerate, the questions is how can I get rid of that. Accessing the indices directly works, but search scripts return http code 400 when I do curl requests with php. Any ideas?

edit:
I removed the folder and created index from the beginning. It did not fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need Fresh Installation with proper security, use xPack or Communication method over private IP Rather using Public IP.